# Import GaBi datasets or database to Brightway2

Tags: brightway

Is there a way to import GaBi datasets or databases to brightway2? In the official [Documentation](https://2.docs.brightway.dev/intro.html#importing-and-exporting) it is not mentioned. Or will there be a possibility in brightway2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such capabilities are not in Brightway. GaBi offers a very interesting model, with a lot of power in its parameterization, but it would be difficult to port this system to Python. To start this work, we would need a GaBi data export, a specification for the data format, and a set of known "good results" to test against.

If you have this material available, feel free to post to the [development mailing list](https://brightway.groups.io/g/development/).

Comment: I thought the export format of GaBi is an ILCD compatible xml file. Shouldn't it be independent of the intern model of GaBi?

Comment: I don't know! Feel free to provide some example export to the the developers mailing list or file an issue with [bw2io](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/issues).